# back to previous activity with intent error

Tags: android, android-intent

I have two activity, on second activity, when  I press enter it will get some value and bring back to first activity.

This is my code:

**second activity**

```
//event on "ENTER" button
Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra("namaDokter", "kosong");
i.putExtra("idDokter", "kosong");
setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
finish();
```

**get its value on first activity**

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    namaDokter=data.getStringExtra("namaDokter");
    idDokter=data.getStringExtra("idDokter");
}
```

but if I don't press "ENTER" button and only press back button from hardware(or Esc key on my keyboard when I'm using emulator), my app crash, I think it's because I don't get any value from `data.getStringExtra("namaDokter");`

what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to check if you got RESULT_OK or not

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode, Intent data)
{
  if(ResultCode == RESULT_OK) {

    namaDokter=data.getStringExtra("namaDokter");
    idDokter=data.getStringExtra("idDokter");
  }else
    //You pressed back
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because when you press the `Enter` Button you pass an intent with values but when you press `Back` then the **activity is finished without passing any intent.**
so you need to add this:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode, Intent data)
{
  if(ResultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    namaDokter=data.getStringExtra("namaDokter");
    idDokter=data.getStringExtra("idDokter");
  }else
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
          "You Pressed Back!",Toast.LENGHT_LONG).show();
}
```

Hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Additional to the existing answers checking the `resultCode` here's another one:

If you want to send the `Intent` even if the user pressed back you can override the `onBackPressed`-method in the second `Activity`:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.putExtra("namaDokter", "kosong");
    i.putExtra("idDokter", "kosong");
    setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```